# My source isn't being recognized as valid

Tags: image, matlab, average

```
source = 'C:\Users\Documents\NAL_Data\09222015\cow_background\';
im_number = 100;
sum = uint32(imread([source,'cow_background-Frame-1'],'tif'));
```

It keeps saying that my file doesn't exist. I'm trying to grab images from a file to do an averaging, but it isn't letting me. I made sure to set the path, but even that didn't do anything.

Comment: What does `dir(source)` print? I recommend to use `fullfile` to concatenate file path.

Comment: To build on what Daniel mentioned, try doing `source = fullfile('C:', 'Users', 'Documents', 'NAL_Data', '09222015', 'cow_background', 'cow_background-Frame-1.tif');`, then do `s = uint32(imread(source));`.  This will allow your code to be platform independent.  Also, if the image doesn't exist.... then the path of where the image is located... that image doesn't really exist.  MATLAB is pretty good with error measures.

Comment: @rayryeng How is using `C:` platform independent?

Comment: @IKavanagh - I actually didn't notice the `C:` until you pointed it out.  I typed it in blindly.  What I said about `fullfile` and platform independency is still valid though.